# Dynamic form partly update with ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a dynamic Form. according to user's selection from dropdown using php and ajax unknown number of new input fields are being added to the form. Problem is when I submit the form it ignores those inputs that generated with ajax. what am I doing wrong?

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
.
.
.
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML="Proceed.";
document.getElementById("5").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","invoice_ajax.php?q="+ test,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Where I put new inputs

```
<form method="post" NAME="mainform" action="pdfinvoice.php">
<div><input type="hidden" readonly name="Owner_City" value="<?php Get_City();?>"></div>
<div><input type="hidden" readonly name="Owner_Post" value="<?php Get_post();?>"></div>
...
<div> <span id="5">Ajax inputs</span></div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are not including any of your code or your HTML source here. That is what you are doing wrong :)

Comment: are you sure those dynamically built `<input/>` fields have a `name` property?

Comment: all of them has names like foo[] because their count is unknown <input type="hidden" name="foo[]" value="bar">

Comment: Have you inspected the dom of your page after the ajax call to make sure you are adding the new input elements inside the form element?

Comment: and so are you referencing them like `foreach( $_REQUEST['foo'] {}` ?

Comment: Referencing them by looping foo array   $_POST['foo'][0])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for save time and easier to development and also cross browser you should use jQuery for you ajax request.
You can refer this topic [jQuery set selected value in option box once the box has been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468605/jquery-set-selected-value-in-option-box-once-the-box-has-been-loaded)